# Differences between element-wise vs jointly concave

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am wondering what the differences are between element-wise and jointly concave functions. How does an element-wise function look? I cannot imagine 2d function which is concave in terms of each variable but not concave jointly.

If we want to maximize a function with multiple variables, we should find the stationary point if the function is jointly concave. What should we do if the function is element-wise concave but not jointly concave? Under what conditions is the stationary point the optimal point if the function is element-wise concave?

Comment: I would call this "concave in each variable/parameter/input" or "partially concave", rather than "element-wise". A simple example is something like $f(x, y) = xy$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the general approach to solving a concave program in each variable? Is the optimal point a corner/boundary point?